# How does GDI::DeleteObject exactly work

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183539(v=vs.85).aspx)

> The DeleteObject function deletes a logical pen, brush, font, bitmap,
>   region, or palette, freeing all system resources associated with the
>   object. After the object is deleted, the specified handle is no longer
>   valid.

So one(myself) would think that once DeleteObject is executed, the HANDLE is no longer valid. but what happens to the objects retrieved by ::GetObject() once i delete the object before saving them with other WinAPI calls?

```
        HFONT hFont = reinterpret_cast<HFONT>(::SendMessage(hwndCtrl, WM_GETFONT, 0, 0));
        if (nullptr == hFont)
        {
            LOG_ERROR(L"Invalid font specified");
            return false;
        }

        LOGFONT font = { 0 };
        if (0 == ::GetObject(hFont, sizeof(font), &font))
        {
            LOG_ERROR(L"Failed getting font");
            return false;
        }

        font.lfHeight = nSize;



       ::DeleteObject(hFont);
        HFONT hFontEx = ::CreateFontIndirect(&font);
        LPARAM lparam = MAKELPARAM(TRUE, 0);
        WPARAM wparam = (WPARAM)(hFontEx);
        SendMessage(hwndCtrl, WM_SETFONT, wparam, lparam);
```

As in the following example, if i decide to delete my HFONT, before sending the new message via SendMessage, i'd retrieve some unexpected results, where other controls gets their font changed, as if i'd generated some kind of a handle leak.

Comment: GetObject() does not return an object, it returns a description of the object.  A LOGFONT in the case of a font.  Deleting the font does not invalidate that struct.  Your code is bugged, you are destroying a font that you did not create.  Accidents are fairly inevitable.  You'll need to depend on that window you are sending the WM_SETFONT message to knowing how to manage the font handle by itself.  It is expected to do that correctly.  Delete the DeleteObject() call, it is a bug.

Comment: Also, after the object from WM_GETFONT is deleted, the gui object will, unsurprisingly, revert to the properties of the default font for the hDC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So one(myself) would think that once DeleteObject is executed, the
>   HANDLE is no longer valid. but what happens to the objects retrieved
>   by ::GetObject() once i delete the object before saving them with
>   other WinAPI calls?

With GetObject you get a description for the object, not a new object. It remains the same after handle deletion.

> As in the following example, if i decide to delete my HFONT, before
>   sending the new message via SendMessage, i'd retrieve some unexpected
>   results, where other controls gets their font changed, as if i'd
>   generated some kind of a handle leak.

If you want to send a message with deleted HFONT, I guess the result will be the same if you send it with any other garbage.